# 7zip / winrar command to extract a folder with path intact to specific folder but excluding parent source path

Tags: command, 7zip

example

There is a file "sample.rar".

Folder structure is: "rising\dawn\ and here there are many (folders1, folders2 and file1, file2)" in this archive.

i have used following command

```
7z.exe x "sample.rar" "rising\dawn\*" -oi:\delete
```

**The result is:**
all files and folders in "rising\dawn\" are extracted to "i:\delete" folder but the empty parent folders "rising\dawn\" are also created in destination folder.

e.g. destination looks:

```
i:\delete\rising\dawn\folder1\file1.bmp

i:\delete\rising\dawn\folder2\subfolder

i:\delete\rising\dawn\file1.txt

i:\delete\rising\dawn\file2.txt
```

**i don't want "rising\dawn\" empty folders to be created but the folder structure there onwards must be as is in the archive.**

**i want the result:**

```
i:\delete\folder1\file1.bmp

i:\delete\folder2\subfolder

i:\delete\file1.txt

i:\delete\file2.txt
```

**at last i found a way out solution. thanks to the winrar support. i have accepted it as an answer below.**

**if you find the question useful don't forget to click the up-vote button.**

Comment: none of the solution worked for me. but at last i found a solution myself. thanks to the winrar support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally this gave me the result.

Thanks to winrar support.

```
rar x -ep1 sample.rar rising\dawn\* d:\e\delete\
```

i have tried other answers given here, this is the only correct answer.
**don't forget to upvote.**

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the archive normally and

1) move the lower level folder/files to where you would like it, then
2) remove the extra top level archive folders.

Code to do so will depend on the exact task.

Comment: Now the question would arise: How to move a folder to its 2 level parent folder in single command?

Comment: Because purpose of programming is to reduce double work. And firing a command two times to is nothing but telling the computer to do the job two times, while it can be done in one.

Answer (score 1):

Using `e` command instead of `x` and add `-r` option works well.

Like this:

```
7z.exe e -r "sample.rar" "rising\dawn\*" -oi:\delete
```

My executable version is "7-Zip [64] 9.20 2010-11-18",
And the platform is Windows 8.1.

This command line eliminates unnecessary parent folders and preserves the hierarchy of folders.

Comment: have you even tried it properly on multiple files and folder archive?
i tested with you answer and it doesn't work.

Comment: have you even tried it properly on an archive with multiple files and folders?
i used '7-Zip 15.14 (2015-12-31) for Windows 7 x64'
i tested with you method. It doesn't work.
all the files (also in subfolder) were extracted to this \delete folder.
and all the subfolders where created in \delete folder and these subfolders were empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the e command rather than the x command:

```
7z.exe e "sample.rar" "scholar\update\*" -oi:\delete
```

Using e instead of x means 7zip will extract all matching files into the same folder (as specified via the -so switch, or the current directory if this isn't specified) rather than preserving the folder structure from inside the archive.

Comment: The question specifies two folders as well as files.  That's a problem.

Comment: As i have asked precisely and the parameter    e   doesn't keep the destination folder structure intact.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I don't think there's any way of doing what you asked with a single 7zip command. The simplest option is to do as foxidrive has suggested.